# How to set youtube-dl Python to always pick 1080p?

Tags: python, youtube-dl

I'm making a Python script to download videos from multiple sites using youtube-dl:

```py
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import youtube_dl

downloadLinks = []

downloadLink = input('Link to download: ')
downloadLinks.append(downloadLink)

youtube_dl_options = {
    "outtmpl": "%(title)s-%(id)s.%(ext)s",
    "restrictfilenames": True,
    "nooverwrites": True,
    "writedescription": True,
    "writeinfojson": True,
    "writeannotations": True,
    "writethumbnail": True,
    "writesubtitles": True,
    "writeautomaticsub": True
}

with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(youtube_dl_options) as ydl:
    ydl.download(downloadLinks)
```

Well the problem is I want to download always the 1080p version of the video, but in some cases it only download the 720p ("best") version, how I can based on code tell to youtube-dl to download the 1080p only.

Comment: What if the video doesn't have 1080p quality?

Comment: Well, there is 1080p 99% and the videos i select are in 1080p, so, i think that's not the problem...

Comment: Have you tried adding `bestvideo[height<=1080]+bestaudio/best[height<=1080]` format template to make it choose the best one that's less or equal to 1080p? Edit: Oh you got it just saw your answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in the options we need to put the format like this:

```py
youtube_dl_options = {
    "format": "mp4[height=1080]", # This will select the specific resolution typed here
    "outtmpl": "%(title)s-%(id)s.%(ext)s",
    "restrictfilenames": True,
    "nooverwrites": True,
    "writedescription": True,
    "writeinfojson": True,
    "writeannotations": True,
    "writethumbnail": True,
    "writesubtitles": True,
    "writeautomaticsub": True
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"best" is the best quality combination of video and audio; specifying only the video resolution may not work. You need to put the audio format like this

```
'format': 'bestvideo[ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/best'
```